# Quarkus, Hibernate ORM and REST - RESTEASY008200: JSON Binding deserialization error:

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I'm trying to create a project that uses Hibernate Panache and Rest, similar to the quickstart on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/hibernate-orm-panache-resteasy.

When I try to `@Post` an entity that extends `PanacheEntity`, as shown below, I get the following error:

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008200: JSON Binding deserialization error: Can't create instance

## Entity

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
class Trade extends PanacheEntity {

    @Column(length = 40, unique = true)
    String name;

}
```

## Rest resource

```java
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/trades")
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class TradeReporterResource {


    @POST
    @Transactional
    public Response add(Trade trade) {
        System.out.println("begin");
        //t.closePrice = trade.closePrice;
        System.out.println("persisting");
        trade.persist();
        System.out.println("persisted");
        return Response.ok(trade).build();
    }
}
```

## Pom dependencies

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

## Problem appears to be with Penache

When I remove the `extends PanacheEntity` from the `Trade` entity, then at least I can POST successfully.

Comment: Would you please specify what you have differently than the quickstart? The quickstart works just fine with both POST and PUT. Have you perhaps omitted `@Transactional` on the RESTEasy Resource?

Comment: I cant see where I'm doing anything overtly different. I've updated my post to  include the resource, and yes it has `@Transactional`.

Comment: Interesting! Would it be possible for you to share a reproducer project that we could check?

Comment: @geoand - please see https://github.com/magick93/Panachegate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turns out to be rather simple, all you need to do is make class `Trade` a **public** class.

It should be noted that this is not a Quarkus limitation, but a JSON-B limitation (which requires de-serialized classes to have a public or protected no-arg constructor - see section 3.7 of the JSON-B spec)